# Java swing Table transparency

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to change the transparency of the JTable to see what behind cells like a photo is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into manipulating the *opacity* of this Swing component?

Comment: I think that you can comment answers posted to your question, I refuse your edit to the answer by @Jakub Zaverka

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using `setOpaque(false)` on the `JTable` and the `TableCellRenderer`. The screenshot is produced by the code below:

[image]

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(
                  "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png"));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.add(new JTable(18, 5) {{
            setOpaque(false);
            setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {{
                setOpaque(false);
            }});
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    });
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set background color to have some alpha component:

```
Color backgound = new Color(0, 0, 0, 255) //total transparency
```

For more help on what you are trying to accomplish, post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: OP's edited your question with follows **This answer coloring the cells it self

but i also tried table.setOpaque(false); and not working i couldn't see what behind the table.**

Comment: What LayoutManager are you using? What do you display behing the table? Just how much transparency do you want? Whole table or just it's background? What about cells? Unless you post more relevant info, we cannot help you any further. Post a short example with the problem.

Comment: I have a jframe with image background and i want to add the jtable to the jframe and see the image behind the table cells

Comment: Is whole table not transparent of just cells? But I implore you, post code or this can go on forever.

Answer (score 1):

I  tried this answer:

```
Color backgound = new Color(0, 0, 0, 255) //total transparency
```

but it didn't work. The following worked:

```
Color backgound = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0) //total transparency
```