# How to make the background of a JTable transparent?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, transparent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java swing Table transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769909/java-swing-table-transparency)

It is not so easy to make a JTable background transparent. I want to see only the text content of my cells.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The table will be transparent if neither itself nor the cells are opaque:

```
table.setOpaque(false);
((DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)).setOpaque(false);
```

If the table is in a `ScrollPane`, it is to make transparent as well:

```
scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
```

At least, you can remove the grid lines:

```
table.setShowGrid(false);
```

Quite a big work for a simply result...

Comment: +1 good answer, however this does not make the header transparent, how can this be achieved?